# Design of Partitioning for Azure Table Storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I have some software which collects data over a large period of time, approx 200 readings per second. It uses an SQL database for this. I am looking to use Azure to move a lot of my old "archived" data to.

The software uses a multi-tenant type architecture, so I am planning to use one Azure Table per Tenant. Each tenant is perhaps monitoring 10-20 different metrics, so I am planning to use the Metric ID (int) as the Partition Key.

Since each metric will only have one reading per minute (max), I am planning to use DateTime.Ticks.ToString("d19") as my RowKey.

I am lacking a little understanding as to how this will scale however; so was hoping somebody might be able to clear this up:

For performance Azure will/might split my table by partitionkey in order to keep things nice and quick. This would result in one partition per metric in this case.

However, my rowkey could potentially represent data over approx 5 years, so I estimate approx 2.5 million rows.

Is Azure clever enough to then split based on rowkey as well, or am I designing in a future bottleneck? I know normally not to prematurely optimise, but with something like Azure that doesn't seem as sensible as normal!

Looking for an Azure expert to let me know if I am on the right line or whether I should be partitioning my data into more tables too.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Few comments:

Apart from storing the data, you may also want to look into how you would want to retrieve the data as that may change your design considerably. Some of the questions you might want to ask yourself:

- When I retrieve the data, will I always be retrieving the data for a particular metric and for a date/time range?
- Or I need to retrieve the data for all metrics for a particular date/time range? If this is the case then you're looking at full table scan. Obviously you could avoid this by doing multiple queries (one query / PartitionKey)
- Do I need to see the most latest results first or I don't really care. If it's former, then your RowKey strategy should be something like `(DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks - DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks).ToString("d19")`.

Also since PartitionKey is a string value, you may want to convert `int` value to a `string` value with some "0" prepadding so that all your ids appear in order otherwise you'll get 1, 10, 11, .., 19, 2, ...etc.

To the best of my knowledge, Windows Azure partitions the data based on `PartitionKey` only and not the `RowKey`. Within a Partition, `RowKey` serves as unique key. Windows Azure will try and keep data with the same `PartitionKey` in the same node but since each node is a physical device (and thus has size limitation), the data may flow to another node as well.

You may want to read this blog post from Windows Azure Storage Team: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/11/06/how-to-get-most-out-of-windows-azure-tables.aspx.

**UPDATE**
Based on your comments below and some information from above, let's try and do some math. This is based on the latest scalability targets published here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/11/04/windows-azure-s-flat-network-storage-and-2012-scalability-targets.aspx. The documentation states that:

> Single Table Partition– a table partition are all of the entities in a
>   table with the same partition key value, and usually tables have many
>   partitions. The throughput target for a single table partition is:
>
> - Up to 2,000 entities per second
> - Note, this is for a single partition, and not a single table. Therefore, a table with good partitioning, can process up to the
>     20,000 entities/second, which is the overall account target described
>     above.

Now you mentioned that you've 10 - 20 different metric points and for for each metric point you'll write a maximum of 1 record per minute that means you would be writing a maximum of 20 entities / minute / table which is well under the scalability target of 2000 entities / second.

Now the question remains of reading. Assuming a user would read a maximum of 24 hours worth of data (i.e. 24 * 60 = 1440 points) per partition. Now assuming that the user gets the data for all 20 metrics for 1 day, then each user (thus each table) will fetch a maximum 28,800 data points. The question that is left for you I guess is how many requests like this you can get per second to meet that threshold. If you could somehow extrapolate this information, I think you can reach some conclusion about the scalability of your architecture.

I would also recommend watching this video as well: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/4-004.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. The likely use case is for a user to request an range of data for an individual metric only. This range will be small (perhaps a 24 hour window). If multiple metrics are required this would be done via multiple queries.

Comment: Additionally, in this case prepadding is not needed, as the metrics don't need to be in a particular order, but thank you for the headsup.

Comment: Updated my answer above. Hope this helps.

Comment: Great, thank you very much. The video was particularly interesting.